# Merging Dictionaries Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Hey guys i want to merge these 45 dictionaries into one. they all have the same keys.

```
d1 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Signal_Iduna_Park_before_the_match_%284th_july_2006%29.jpg/150px-Signal_Iduna_Park_before_the_match_%284th_july_2006%29.jpg', 'Stadium': 'Westfalenstadion', 'Capacity': '81,365', 'City': 'Dortmund', 'Population': '586,852', 'Postal Code': '44001-44388', 'State': 'North Rhine-Westphalia', 'Home Team': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Opened Year': '1974', 'Notes': 'UEFA Category 4 stadium'}
d2 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/M%C3%BCnchen_-_Allianz-Arena_%28Luftbild%29.jpg/150px-M%C3%BCnchen_-_Allianz-Arena_%28Luftbild%29.jpg', 'Stadium': 'Allianz Arena', 'Capacity': '75,000', 'City': 'Munich', 'Population': '1,487,708', 'Postal Code': '80331–81929', 'State': 'Bavaria', 'Home Team': 'FC Bayern Munich', 'Opened Year': '2005', 'Notes': 'UEFA Category 4 stadium'}
d3 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Olympiastadionberlin2005.JPG/150px-Olympiastadionberlin2005.JPG', 'Stadium': 'Olympiastadion Berlin', 'Capacity': '74,475', 'City': 'Berlin', 'Population': '3,677,472', 'Postal Code': '', 'State': 'Berlin', 'Home Team': 'Hertha BSC', 'Opened Year': '1936', 'Notes': 'UEFA Category 4 stadium'}
d4 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Olympiastadion_Muenchen.jpg/150px-Olympiastadion_Muenchen.jpg', 'Stadium': 'Olympiastadion Munich', 'Capacity': '69,250', 'City': 'Munich', 'Population': '1,487,708', 'Postal Code': '80331–81929', 'State': 'Bavaria', 'Home Team': 'Various', 'Opened Year': '1972', 'Notes': ''}
d5 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/2010-06-03_Arena_AufSchalke_01.jpg/150px-2010-06-03_Arena_AufSchalke_01.jpg', 'Stadium': 'Veltins-Arena', 'Capacity': '62,271', 'City': 'Gelsenkirchen', 'Population': '', 'Postal Code': '45801-45899', 'State': 'North Rhine-Westphalia', 'Home Team': 'FC Schalke 04', 'Opened Year': '2001', 'Notes': 'UEFA Category 4 stadium'}
d6 = {'Image': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Blick_vom_Rotenberg_Stadion.jpg/150px-Blick_vom_Rotenberg_Stadion.jpg', 'Stadium': 'Mercedes-Benz Arena', 'Capacity': '60,469', 'City': 'Stuttgart', 'Population': '626,275', 'Postal Code': '70173–70619', 'State': 'Baden-Württemberg', 'Home Team': 'VfB Stuttgart', 'Opened Year': '1933', 'Notes': 'UEFA Category 4 stadium'}
```

I tried it with defaultdict and update but it didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by merging?

Comment: `[d1, d2, d3, ...]`

Comment: @luk2302 I suspect he wants `{'Image': [list of all the images], 'Stadium': [list of all the stadiums], ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, do the following:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(list)
for d in [d1, d2, d3...]:
    for key, value in d.items():
        d[key].append(value)
```